# Selecting from two different JSON columns resulting in n^2 rows instead of n

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, join

I have a JSON document such as this:

```
{"cases":[1983,2188, etc.],"deaths":[78,84, etc.]});
```

I'm trying to see them side by side using:

```
SELECT dd::numeric AS deaths, cc::numeric AS cases
FROM covid_json, json_array_elements_text(info->'deaths') dd, json_array_elements_text(info->'cases') cc
```

`cases` and `deaths` both have a length of 51, but the query above gives 2601 (51^2) rows such as this:

[image]

What should I do to prevent these values from repeating for each row?

Comment: You need to tell them how to join, just like a regular table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to unnest [`with ordinality`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html). This adds an index number to each element, that you can then use to `join`:

```
select d.deaths, c.cases
from covid_json cj
cross join lateral json_array_elements(cj.info -> 'cases') with ordinality as d(deaths, rn)
inner join lateral json_array_elements(cj.info -> 'deaths') with ordinality as c(cases, rn) 
    on c.rn = d.rn
```

This assumes that both arrays have the same number of elements, as explained in your question.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f1a892d29c72d2293189e2017d299c84)**.

Sample data:

```
| info                                                |
| :-------------------------------------------------- |
| {"cases":[1983, 2188, 2615], "deaths": [78,84, 87]} |
```

Results:

```
deaths | cases
:----- | :----
1983   | 78   
2188   | 84   
2615   | 87
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of documentation, this also works:

```
SELECT json_array_elements_text(info->'deaths') AS deaths, json_array_elements_text(info->'cases') AS cases
FROM covid_json
```